# Integration and function composition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I would like to know which are the conditions on the continuous functions $h$ and $g$ for the following equality to be true:

$$ \int_{X} (h \circ g) (x)dx = \int_{W} h(w)dw,  $$

where $X$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$ and $W = g(X)$.

I thought that $g$ needed to be injective but I have found counter examples when $g$ and $h$ are both injective...

Comment: Shouldn't the first integrand be $(h\circ g)(x)$?

Comment: I have edited it. I thought there would not be any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a change of variable $w=g(x)$; to be a *true* change of variable you certainly want $g$ to be injective. Then
$$
x=g^{-1}(w),\quad dx=\frac{dg^{-1}(w)}{dw}\,dw.
$$The formula for the change of variable gives
$$
\int_X(h\circ g)(x)\,dx=\int_W h(w)\,\frac{dg^{-1}(w)}{dw}\,dw.
$$
If you want the equalty to hold for all $f$ you need $g(x)=x+C$. Otherwise, for a given $g$, the equality will hold for functions $h$ such that
$$
\int_W h(w)\Bigl(\frac{dg^{-1}(w)}{dw}-1\Bigr)\,dw=0.
$$

Comment: But $g$ is assumed to be continuous only.